# How to create a dictionary of values that contain a tuple and list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to define a function to create a dictionary like so:

```
d = {}
d['aod'] = [('nt', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']),
            ('t', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']),
            ('nv', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3'])]
```

I'm able to get the dictionary looking like this:

```
d = {'aod': ('nt', 'P3')}
```

With the code below:

```
experiment = ['aod']
cond_peaks = ['nt_P3', 't_P3', 'nv_P3']
channel_lst = ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']

def create_dict(experiment, cond_peaks, channel_lst):
    d = {}
    for e in experiment:
        for cp in cond_peaks: 
            cond = cp.split('_')[0]
            peak = cp.split('_')[1]
            cond_peak_tup = cond, peak
            d[e] = cond_peak_tup
    return d
```

Since tuples are immutable I can't add `channel_lst`  to the dictionary value.  My question is how can I create a dictionary where the value contains a tuple and a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your tuple like so:

```
cond_peak_tup = cond, peak, channel_lst
```

and use a temporary list,

```
d = {}
for e in experiment:
    l = []
    for cp in cond_peaks: 
        cond = cp.split('_')[0]
        peak = cp.split('_')[1]
        cond_peak_tup = cond, peak, channel_lst
        l.append(cond_peak_tup)
    d[e] = l
return d
```

More elegantly, you could also create everything in one go using dictionary and list comprehensions (assuming Python 3.5 or newer for the `(*cp.split('_'), channel_lst)` syntax):

```
d = {e: [(*cp.split('_'), channel_lst) for cp in cond_peaks]
     for e in experiment}
```

For older versions, you would have to do something akin to:

```
d = {e: [tuple(cp.split('_') + [channel_lst]) for cp in cond_peaks]
     for e in experiment}
```

Not only is the latter solution faster, it is also more readable for the Pythonically literate, in my opinion, while the former is useful for learning or debugging purposes.  But this is, of course, a matter of style.

Comment: `@Evey` - what is the function of  `*` in `(*cp.split('_')`?

Comment: @e9e9s If `xs = [x1, x2, x3]`, the star (`*`) in the expression `(*xs, y)` expands the list (or any iterable, actually) such that `(*xs, y) == (x1, x2, x3, y)`.  Since `cp.split('_')` returns a list, these are inserted into the tuple in the above manner. See PEP 448 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for additional examples. The notation has actually existed for functions for a long time, where `f(y, *xs) == f(y, x1, x2, x3)`, and a similar syntax works when defining functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within `dict comprehension` in one line like this example with this input:

```
experiment = ['aod']
cond_peaks = ['nt_P3', 't_P3', 'nv_P3']
channel_lst = ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']

final = {k:[(j.split("_")[0],j.split("_")[1],channel_lst,) for j in cond_peaks] for k in experiment}


print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'aod': [('nt', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']), ('t', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3']), ('nv', 'P3', ['af1', 'af2', 'af3'])]}
```

Comment: The `tuple(j.split("_") + channel_lst)` does not produce the desired output as it concatenates the two lists. You have to do `tuple(j.split("_") + [channel_lst])` as shown in the last part of my answer.

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't check it. Thanks for your comment.